# mathplotlib six.moves.urllib.request import error

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I just had this problem while trying to import mathplotlib.

This was the error I was getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xxx/solver.py", line 7, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: cannot import name urlopen
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution I used to fix this issue.  It took me a while to figure this out and I couldn't find any references online that helped me, so I am posting the solution here.

I replaced the offending line in matplotlib/**init**.py

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
```

with:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

which allowed me to see the real error:

```
import socket
  File "C:\PROJECTS\xxx\socket.py", line 7, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

So the problem was that I had named one of my modules "socket.py" and this was causing an error, which was masked by the six.moves importing mechanism.  This file was stacked fairly deep in my project tree, but it happened to be at the same level as the script I was trying to run, which is presumably why it was being imported at the root level.

I was using PyCharm on windows for all of this.